# How to do permutation in tsql (set based)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, permutation

I have the below input

```
PlayerID    MatchPlayed RunsMade
--------    ----------- --------
1           10              200
2           5               100
3           8               24
4           30              50
```

The output will be

```
Combined Players    Combined Match Played   Combined runs Made  
----------------    ---------------------   ------------------  
1                   10                      200         
1,2                 15                      300         
1,3                 18                      224
1,4                 40                      250
1,2,3               23                      324
1,2,4               45                      350
1,3,4               48                      274
1,2,3,4             53                      374
2                   5                       100
2,3                 13                      124
2,4                 35                      150
2,3,4               43                      174
3                   8                       24
3,4                 38                      74
4                   30                      50
```

The **Combined Match Played** column is the sum of the values of *Match Played column of those players*. e.g. for Combined Played 1,2 the Combined Match Played value is 10 + 5 = 15.

similarly, Combined Runs Made is the sum of the Runs MAde column of the individual players. e.g. for the same example, the Combined Runs MAde column is 200 +100  =300.

Thanks

Comment: Whilst I'm sure this _can_ be done in T-SQL, I would advise performing the permutation in a different language e.g. VB.Net / C# / C++ etc.  The query that would be required to generate this output is likely to be complex and may well get more so as more players are brought into the mix.

Comment: That's correect but there is hardly any choice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setup:

```
create table Input(PlayerId int, MatchPlayed int, RunsMade int)

insert Input
  select 1, 10, 200
  union all select 2, 5, 100
  union all select 3, 8, 24
  union all select 4, 30, 50
```

Query:

```
with cte(Combined, PlayerId, MatchPlayed, RunsMade)
as
(
    select cast(PlayerId as varchar(500)), PlayerId, MatchPlayed, RunsMade
    from Input
    union all
    select cast(cte.Combined + ',' + cast(inp.PlayerId as varchar) as varchar(500)), inp.PlayerId, inp.MatchPlayed + cte.MatchPlayed, inp.RunsMade + cte.RunsMade
    from cte
        join Input inp on
            cte.PlayerId < inp.PlayerId
)
select Combined, MatchPlayed, RunsMade
from cte
order by Combined
```

Comment: can you send some sample tutorial for meaning of combined. Sorry, not getting how CTE.combined is being used here.